# What is difference between function within class constructor function and the method Inside class but outside constructor function (in js)?

Tags: javascript, class, methods, constructor

What is difference between function within class constructor function and the method Inside class but outside constructor function (in js)?

I tried to search about this and did not find something understandable for me!

Thanks in advance!

```
  class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;

    /* this function within the constructor what is it’s difference
      from the method(1) below */

    withinFunction = function () { console.log(“This is rectangle”)};
  }
  
  // Method(1)
  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

Comment: *"I tried to search about this and did not find something understandable for me!"* ... I doubt that ... [MDN :: Class body and method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Class_body_and_method_definitions)

Comment: Because your code does not declare `withinFunction`, that creates a global variable. If it were declared with `let` or `const`, it would be a local symbol in the constructor function and it would not affect constructed objects at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that **specific** example, the code is falling prey to what I call [**The Horror of Implicit Globals**](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). `withinFunction` is a **global variable** (unless it's declared somewhere you haven't shown).

The more normal version is this:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;

    this.withinFunction = function () { console.log(“This is rectangle”)};
//  ^^^^^
  }
  
  // Method(1)
  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

The difference is that `withinFunction` is created every time the constructor is called, and assigned as an "own" property on the object being created. In contrast, `calcArea` (defined using *method syntax*) is created *once* when the `class` construct is evaluated and put on the object that's assigned as the prototype of objects created via the constructor (`Rectangle.prototype`). So there's only one copy of `calcArea` that's shared by all instances, but `withinFunction` is created separately for each instance.

They both have their uses, particularly when `withinFunction` is created using arrow function syntax rather than traditional function syntax.

If you're using `class` syntax, in general it's best to prefer method syntax for the sharing aspect (though modern JavaScript engines are very efficient at having multiple function objects sharing the same code) and because it's easier to mock prototype functions for testing.